# Provide helper functions to dll loaded with LoadLibrary()

Tags: c++, dll, plugins, linker, loadlibrary

I want to provide helper functions to the plugin implementation. If I load the plugin dll with LoadLibrary is it possible to call from inside the plugin a function from the dll that loaded it?

Pseudocode:
main.dll:

```
using FNPtr = int (*)(void);
auto dllHandle = LoadLibrary("path/plugin.dll");
auto func = (FNPtr) GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "func1");
auto i = func();
```

plugin.dll:

```
#include <helperFuncs.h>

extern "C" int func1()
{
   return main::helperFunc(2);
}
```

Comment: Typically, the DLL would provide some form of `InitializeMe` function, that would take as parameters whatever information it needs from the host; e.g. callback pointers. The host would then initialize the DLL first thing after loading it.

Comment: Yes, it's possible if the functions you want to call are exported as well.